# Javascript is it bad practice to return an object that is passed by reference

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

Let's say I have this function in JavaScript:

```js
function foo(a) {
  a.item = "four"
  return a
}

b = {
  item: "three"
}
b = foo(b)
console.log(b)
```

Since JavaScript is a call-by-sharing language there is no need to `return a`, the object `b` would have the same final value with the below code:

```js
function foo(a) {
  a.item = "four"
  return a
}

b = {
  item: "three"
}
foo(b)
console.log(b)
```

**Is it bad practice to use `return b` for better readability even though it is not needed**

Are there any downsides to returning the object?

Comment: Why would returning b have better readability?

Comment: @meriton `b` is reused in the code and `foo()` is in another file. Therefore, there is no need to look inside `foo()`(changing file)  to know that `foo()` is manipulating `b`. This is why, in my opinion, its more readable.. the reader knows faster that b has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, in your example the return statement is unnecessary, strictly speaking. Also, just as a point of clarification, while JS passes objects by reference, primitive types are passed by value.

However, it is considered a JS best practice to avoid mutating function parameters. It can very quickly get very confusing when you have many functions performing actions on the same object that is getting passed around and mutated. So, in fact, I would consider it a bad practice to write a mutating function that does **not** involve returning a value.

Following that idea, your example would look like:

```
function foo(a) {
  // Copy our input (assuming 'a' only contains primitive values)
  const output = { ...a };
  output.item = 'four';
  return output;
}

const b = { item: 'three' };
const c = foo(b);

// b is unchanged
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `Array.prototype.sort()` method returns the array even though it's sorting it in place.

Whether this provides better readability is a matter of personal preference. But it can make it easier to work with arrays/objects that are created on the fly, e.g.

```
sorted_words = string.split(" ").sort();
```

If it didn't return the array, you'd have to do this in two steps:

```
sorted_words = string.split(" ")
sorted_words.sort();
```